# wrong redirection using return RedirectToAction

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I need to redirect the user from one controller to other controller.

I'm using

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Project");
```

It worked great unless I published my web.My web is running in a IIS directory,but the url looks like this

```
http://localhost/Project/index
```

but it should be right

```
http://localhost/webapp/Project/index
```

EDIT

What do you mean with `Is there a "/" in beginning of your routing?` ?

Yes, the directory is set to an IIS application.

There's nothing special but here it is:

```
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );
        }
```

Comment: That's not possible. You gotta be missing something from your description. `RedirectToAction` works perfectly fine and takes into account the virtual directory your application is deployed under. So wrong javascript, wrong routing, hardcoded url somewhere else, wrongly deployed application in IIS ...? The possibilities are multiple but definitely not `RedirectToAction`.

Comment: It could be wrongly deployed application in IIS. I just created an directory in the wwwroot directory and set it up to an IIS application (.NET 4 integrated pool). Then I used the publish option in Visual Studio and pointed it to this directory (file system path).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Is there a "/" in beginning of your routing?
- Did you make sure the virtual directory is set as Application in IIS?

Add your routing rules to the question to help you more (and then please comment on the answer when you do to let me know that you did, thanks).t

Comment: Your routes look correct, did you try to publish to IIS instead to file system?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the path from

```
 http://localhost/Project/index
```

to

```
 http://localhost/webapp/Project/index
```

then put the prefix in your Route registration, like :

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
     {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "webapp/{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "webapp/{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );
```